# Induction by assume-guarantee with nuSMV

Tags: model-checking, induction, spin, nusmv

I have an asynchronous symmetric ring-shaped protocol with 5 processes that satisfies a given property. I want to prove (or get counterexample) that the property is true for protocols with 6 number of processes and more; that is

> ### ∀n.φ(n)

I decided to use **assume-guarantee** and I’m using `nuSMV` for model-checking.

I know that former versions of **SMV** like `Cadence` could support this feature but is there any way to implement assume-guarantee in `nuSMV`?
If there is not, could I use other model checkers like `SPIN` instead?

Thank you.